# Comunities Article Detail

Tags: community, detail

I have been trying to add the article detail page to a navigational menu and keep getting an error when I try to save it.  Everything looks correct, I can view the article detail page, but I must be overlooking something.

[image]enter image description here

Comment: Seems, you need to remove the (:) from the URL.

Comment: yes, remove the : as @Devendra suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just tested with the sample URL and you need to remove ":" and add proper URL of the article you want in Navigation .

Comment: Thank you Mohith for responding, the only URL I see is the one on the article detail page which is /article/urlname/ I have removed the : but it does not find the page.  In the template editor, it only show the URL of the sitestudio.na30.force.com/sfsites/picasso/core/config/commeditor.jsp when I view it so not sure..

Comment: You need to input the URL of the article you need the view for